# insert not functioning mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i got one problem with this . everytime i go insert it the page just refresh and blank. i dont know where is the problem but i checked my sql the data i use is the same. so i dont know where the problem is.

```
                      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">    <tr>
                        <td> Generic Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" name = "gname"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> Brand Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" name = "bname"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> Quantity:<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name = "mqty"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> Description:<input type="text" class="form-control" name = "mdesc"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <br>
                        <tr>
                        <td> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="add" Value="Add"></td>
                        </tr>
               </form>

                <?php
                include "../../functions/connect.php";
                error_reporting(0);

                    date_default_timezone_set('Singapore');
                    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());



                    ?>

                    <?php
                    include "../../functions/connect.php"; 
                    extract($_POST);



                    if(isset($add)){

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_meds`(`date`,`generic`,`brand`,`description`,`medqty`) VALUES ('$date','$gname','$bname','$mdesc','$mqty')";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Verification Error: " . mysql_error());


                    }



            ?>
```

EDIT: Result of `var_dump($_POST)` -

```
array(5) { 
    ["gname"]=> string(11) "Paracetamol" 
    ["bname"]=> string(8) "Biogesic" 
    ["mqty"]=> string(3) "100" 
    ["mdesc"]=> string(71) "The most prescribed Headache and Fever brand that's Effective and Safe." 
    ["add"]=> string(4) "Save" 
 }
```

Comment: `$add` that's undefined. This doesn't help `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: the button is named add. <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="add" Value="Add">

Comment: where did you define $add parameter?

Comment: With `error_reporting(0);` you'll never know where the problem is. Turn the errors on and (many times) they will teach you how to code.

Comment: here @hakkikonu <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="add" Value="Add">

Comment: Maybe `if(isset($_POST['add'])){` ?

Comment: So `var_dump($add)`, check if it is extracted

Comment: Also why do you include php-file twice?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` just to confirm what is in the array. Edit your post to include that output.

Comment: array(5) { ["gname"]=> string(11) "Paracetamol" ["bname"]=> string(8) "Biogesic" ["mqty"]=> string(3) "100" ["mdesc"]=> string(71) "The most prescribed Headache and Fever brand that's Effective and Safe." ["add"]=> string(4) "Save" } here. same data's

Comment: saw it. its with the description . it doesnt accept that's which has a ' . anyway the sql could accept such thing?

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" why you're using this?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Value="Add" -> value="Add" just try

Comment: Please don't dump code in a comment, edit your original post and include it there.

Comment: Why don't you just make it easy on yourself and replace `if(isset($add))` with `if(isset($_POST["add"]))` - You also haven't told us where `$add` is defined (nor how), and inside what file. You obviously have an insert issue with the apostrophe in `that's Effective` so you should be escaping your data. `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would have signaled the error. `error_reporting(0);` really doesn't help you. Turn it on, not off.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST["add"])){
```

this will work for you

your form has **POST** method. So on PHP side you have to handle it with `$_POST` global variable.

Comment: dont use `extract()` for this problem. Delete it and put `$_POST["add"]` to your if statement

Comment: Why he shouldn't use `extract`? Are there any reasons?

Comment: None @u_mulder, none at all.

Comment: Try to remove second inclusion of php-file, there can be functions that are redefined.